# Sections Of DNA

Tags: biochemistry, dna, dna-helix

I know what major (2.2 nm) and minor (1.2 nm) groves are, but what is then name for:

- a 360-degree rotation of DNA (3.4 nm)
- the gap between each base pair (0.34 nm)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The term for distance covered in a 360° rotation of helix is known as the **pitch** of DNA helix, though there is no special name for distance covered between 2 base pairs. It can be called as **rise per base pair** of DNA. See the table below from [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nucleic_acid_double_helix) article:

[image: table]

*Reference:* [Nucleic Acid Double Helix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nucleic_acid_double_helix)

Comment: 458 views :) wow !

Answer (score 6):

It turns out that the gap between (heterocyclic nitrogenous) base pairs is called 'adjacent base pair width'. Also, the pitch (10 base pairs long) is also known as 'one helical turn'. Just a bit of additional information...

Comment: it is (kind of) mandatory here to give some references to your answer (even if its on your own question) so that other readers can have a source for more information.